# Is It Possible To Remove 'Convert To Case' From Email Record?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

In CRM 2013 I would like to remove from the command bar of an email record the 'To Case' option from the 'Convert To' sub-menu.  I have removed the 'To Lead' option from the same sub-menu by modifying a security role so that privilege of the read action for the lead entity is none.  I have set the privilege of the read action for the case entity to none but the 'To Case' option remains in the sub-menu.  The changes to the security role are in use by CRM as the Cases option is no longer present in the Service menu.

Is it possible to remove 'To Case' from the 'Convert To' menu and if so please could someone tell me how?

The 'To Enquiry' option exists in the sub-menu because I renamed the Opportunity entity to Enquiry.

[image: Email Record]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. Try to use [Ribbon Workbench](http://www.develop1.net/public/page/Ribbon-Workbench-for-Dynamics-CRM-2011.aspx).

Comment: Thank you.  I have managed to achieve what I was intending by using the Ribbon Workbench.

Out of interest do you know why the 'To Lead' and the 'To Case' sub-menu options behave differently i.e. why isn't the 'To Case' option affected by security roles yet the 'To Lead' is.  It seems odd that a CRM user would be given the option to convert an email to a case when they do not have access to read case records.